# CSS :focus applying style even if I haven't interacted

Tags: css, forms, input, sass

I'm using the :focus property on an input so that when I click on it an effect occurs. However, even when I don't click on it, all the inputs have had the style contained within :focus applied as soon as I load the page.

```css
.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.form {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 7rem;
  padding-right: 7rem;
  padding-top: 5rem;
}

.form input {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: #595f6e;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.form input:focus+.label-name .content-name,
.form input:valid+.label-name .content-name {
  transform: translateY(-150%);
  color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form input:focus+.label-name::after,
.form input:valid+.label-name::after {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.form label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.form label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.content-name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="input-container u-margin-bottom-medium">
    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
                            <span class="content-name">Name</span>
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container u-margin-bottom-medium">
    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
                            <span class="content-name">Email</span>
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container u-margin-bottom-medium">
    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
                            <span class="content-name">Message</span>
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You are setting the same styles as the focus state when the the input is valid, which they will be by default

Comment: Ok. The tutorial I was following did that so when you put in the text the style wouldn't revert. Do you know of any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to test if there is text in the `input`, but want to wait until it's "valid" (this does not check to see if the actual data is valid, but rather that there is text). You can set the `required` attribute on the `input` fields. Technically, if there is no text in the `input` field, the field isn't "valid" until there is.

```css
.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.form {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 7rem;
  padding-right: 7rem;
  padding-top: 5rem;
}

.form input {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: #595f6e;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.form input:focus+.label-name .content-name,
.form input:valid+.label-name .content-name {
  transform: translateY(-150%);
  color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form input:focus+.label-name::after,
.form input:valid+.label-name::after {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.form label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.form label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.content-name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="input-container u-margin-bottom-medium">
    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
                            <span class="content-name">Name</span>
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container u-margin-bottom-medium">
    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
                            <span class="content-name">Email</span>
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container u-margin-bottom-medium">
    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="name" class="label-name">
                            <span class="content-name">Message</span>
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```